# Javascript to load a #subpage upon loading document

Tags: javascript, load

My Javascript is poor, but I have made a site with subpages that are loaded by revealing divs using Javascript functions: http://thenethersphere.com/  Observe the Gateway page is loaded by default, which is fine.

My objective is to determine which of the three URL is being requested by the client, e.g. #gateway (default), #comms, or #library and trigger the requisite function to actually load a subpage if the user goes to, e.g. thenethersphere.com/#comms or thenethersphere.com/gateway.vs#comms would cause the page to run showComms(), which looks basically like this:

```
function showComms() {
    hideGateway();
    hideLibrary();
    document.getElementById("comms").style.left = "11em";
    document.getElementById("comms").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("lcarsmain1").style.color = "#FF9900";
    document.getElementById("lcarsmain2").style.color = "#FF9900";
    document.getElementById("lcarsmain3").style.color = "#FF9900";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `location.hash` to get the relevant part of the url and call the appropriate function ..

example

```
var section = location.hash.slice(1);
if (section == 'comms') showComms();
```